# Wie kann man „industry reputation“ ins Deutsch übersetzen?

Tags: translation, compound

Wie kann man „industry reputation“ ins Deutsch übersetzen? 
Der ganze Satz:

> The Guild’s primary role is as an advocate for pharmacists in relation to pharmacy ownership rules and *industry reputation*.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. After reading all your responses I think it's referring to the role of the Guild overseeing the reputation of those community pharmacies subscribed to it *in* the pharmacy industry, so Barth Zalewski's answer looks like the more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da **industry** nicht nur Industrie, sondern auch "Branche, Gebiet" bezeichnet, würde ich zu den folgenden Übersetzungen tendieren:

> Reputation / Ansehen / Autorität (in) der Branche / auf dem (Fach-)Gebiet

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde es so übersetzen : "Ansehen der Industrie"

http://www.schwaebische.de/region/baden-wuerttemberg_artikel,-Bosch-Chef-wegen-Airport-Desaster-in-Sorge-um-Ansehen-der-Industrie-_arid,5382162.html